# Magento 2 get config values in view/frontend/web/template/payment .html file

Tags: magento2, payment-methods

I want to get **`system config value`** in **frontend template**.
Path like **`"view/frontend/web/template/payment/payment.html"`**
How it's?
Please help me.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please follow below steps

Step 1 : Add below code to

> app/code/Vendor/ModuleName/view/frontend/web/js/view/payment.js

file

```
define([
    'ko',
    'jquery',
    'uiComponent',
    'mage/storage',
    'mage/url'
], function (ko, $, Component, storage, url) {
    'use strict';

    return Component.extend({
        defaults: {
            template: 'Vendor_ModueName/payment/payment'
        },
        getconfigValue: function () {
            var serviceUrl = url.build('modulename/custom/storeconfig');

            storage.get(serviceUrl).done(
                function (response) {
                    if (response.success) {
                        return response.value
                    }
                }
            ).fail(
                function (response) {
                    return response.value
                }
            );
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

Step 1 : Create controller

> app/code/Vendor/ModuleName/Controller/Custom/Storeconfig.php

file and Add below code

```
namespace Vendor\ModuleName\Controller\Custom;

class Storeconfig extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{

    protected $resultJsonFactory;

    protected $storeManager;

    protected $scopeConfig;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory $resultJsonFactory,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
    ) {
        $this->resultJsonFactory = $resultJsonFactory;
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    /**
     * Execute view action
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        $response = [];
        try {
            $configValue = $this->scopeConfig->getValue(
                'your/path/config',
                \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE
            );
            $response = [
                'success' => true,
                'value' => __($configValue)
            ];

        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $response = [
                'success' => false,
                'value' => __($e->getMessage())
            ];
            $this->messageManager->addError($e->getMessage());
        }
        $resultJson = $this->resultJsonFactory->create();
        return $resultJson->setData($response);
    }

}
```

Step 3 : Show config value using **.html** file as per below code.

```
<div class="config-data-show" data-bind="html: getconfigValue"></div>
```

Comment: Please check it with my code.

Comment: Thanks for reply.
Please tell me in js file "htmltemplatefilepath" it's start to Vendor/ModuleName/../payment.html OR app/code/Vendor/ModuleName/../payment.html OR ....?

And what is "classname" in .html ?

Comment: htmltemplatefilepath means Vendor_ModueName/payment/payment (view/frontend/web/template/payment/payment.html) and Please check, i have updated my answer(code)

Comment: You will add payment.js file's code on your Component js and create new controller file as per my code

Comment: same payment.js file code add in my Component js then error  "ReferenceError: getCode is not defined" in console.

Comment: and if replace your code "uiComponent" to "Magento_Checkout/js/view/payment/default" then print(view) on page same like
**
function () { var serviceUrl = url.build('custompayment/custom/storeconfig'); storage.get(serviceUrl).done( function (response) { if (response.success) { return response.value } } ).fail( function (response) { return response.value } ); return false; } **

Comment: Please send me the location of that file and function where you add that code. so i will check it in my local system and i will provide solution of that error

Comment: Check my provided solution, add only (not all code) my function 'getconfigValue'  to your uiComponent file and also define 'mage/storage' and 'mage/url' to this uiComponent. in last follow the step 3. Check it and let me know in detail in the case of js related issue

Comment: Js file path  : Vendor/Modulename/view/frontend/web/js/view/payment/method-renderer/payment.js

Comment: how to define 'mage/storage' and 'mage/url' in js file

Comment: 'mage/storage' and 'mage/url' at top of the js file. for example :  
define([
    ....,
    'mage/storage',
    'mage/url',
    ....
]

Comment: if not working then please send me your payment.js code. because getCode function is require on payment js file. if not then it will throw  error 'ReferenceError: getCode is not defined'

Comment: define([
    'ko',
    'jquery',
    'uiComponent',
    'mage/storage',
    'mage/url'
], function (ko, $, Component, storage, url) {
    'use strict';
    return Component.extend({
        defaults: {
            template: 'Emipro_Custompayment/payment/custompayment'
        },
        getconfigValue: function () {
            var serviceUrl = url.build('custompayment/custom/storeconfig');
            storage.get(serviceUrl).done(
                ...
            ).fail(
                ...
            );
            return false;
        }
    });
});

Comment: If you are getting error 'ReferenceError: getCode is not defined' then you need to define getCode : function() {
            return 'payment_method_code';
        } Function to UiComponent js file. Like This return Component.extend({ 
  defaults: { template: 'Emipro_Custompayment/payment/custompayment' }, 
  getconfigValue: function () { 
   var serviceUrl = url.build('custompayment/custom/storeconfig'); 
   storage.get(serviceUrl).done(  ).fail(   ); 
   return false; 
  },
  getCode : function() {
            return 'payment_method_code';
        }
 });

Comment: Add only (not all code) my function 'getconfigValue' to your uiComponent js file

Comment: I had create custom payment method module on magento 2 and it is completely working for me. I think you have missing some function to UiComponent js file

Comment: My default js file was :
define(
    [
        'Magento_Checkout/js/view/payment/default'
    ],
    function (Component) {
        'use strict';
 
        return Component.extend({
            defaults: {
                template: 'Emipro_Custompayment/payment/custompayment'
            }
        });
    }
);

Comment: Check this https://www.classyllama.com/blog/how-to-create-payment-method-magento-2 link for create custom payment method module.

Comment: Finally i found that response storage.get is fail and resonse link '{"readyState":4,"responseText":"<!doctype html>\n<html lang=\"en\">\n    <head >\n        <script>\n    var BASE_URL...'. so what is problem in serviceUrl response, Now please help me

Comment: How to check from here controller call or not ?

Comment: Go to Browser, Press F12  and check console or network area with XHR.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88905/discussion-on-answer-by-saneer-ladani-magento-2-get-config-values-in-view-fronte).